# RegExp converting military time JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, match

I am trying to convert military time from a string with regex... what I have so far is

```
var a = "[18:37:56]";
var b = a.replace(/(\[|\])/g,'');
var c = b.match(/^[0-9][0-9]/);
var d = Number(c[0]) > 12 ? Number(c[0]) - 12 : Number(c[0]);
b.replace(/^[0-9][0-9]/,d);
```

The first replace is to get rid of the square brackets. Then we match the first two numbers, then after this we will see if that number is greater than 12, if so subtract 12 if not leave it alone. Then replace those numbers with the corresponding number.

Problem is for one, what if the for c there is no second number, meaning it's only at 12:01am or 9:59am in standard time. I'm seeing a lot of flaws that can come up with this, does anyone have any better solutions than what I've done?

Comment: Use modulo, `18 % 12 === 6`

Comment: Can you explain modulo is that with Vanilla JS? and what is the `%` for in terms of here.

Comment: See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: change `var c = b.match(/^[0-9]{1,2}/);` to handle the single number issue

Comment: @elclanrs Ok ok, pretty deep stuff there lol. So modular arithmetic would work here. I get this, but like I've never needed the `%` before, is that literally the modulo?

Comment: @elclanrs thanks again for this because you've opened a whole new ball park for me :) I appreciate this dearly. I don't learn these thing until I actually need them.

Comment: The modulo operator gives you the remainder of a division. It's useful for many things, like figuring out if a number is odd or even, do something every nth iteration, etc...

Comment: hmm I'll have to read more on this as this sounds awesome. Thanks again mate I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One-liner:

```
alert("[18:37:56]".substr(1,8).replace(/^\d\d?/,function(m) {return (m%12)||12;}));
```

If you want to append `am` or `pm`:

```
"[18:37:56]".replace(/\[(\d\d?)(:\d\d:\d\d)\]/,function(_,h,ms) {return ((h%12)||12)+ms+(h>=12?"p":"a")+"m";});
```

Comment: This looks nice and simple, though the issue arrises again with the substring as it won't always have 8 characters ;)

Comment: See edit - the second code does everything at once and allows for the single-digit case (although usually military time has a leading zero anyway)

Comment: Ok let me see how this chat works, I'm going to change my time on my computer (if that is what it's going by) and see if their is a leading zero) if not whatever ;)

Comment: I took it off. Realized just now that I clicked it when reading.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol why is your regex looking through the minutes and seconds? Just curious mate

Comment: @EasyBB Because it needs to cut off the `]` at the end and put the `am/pm` there - as you can see in the replacement it just leaves the `ms` untouched.

Comment: yes yes, now that I've used it and analyzed it more I see this. Thanks I'm going to accept your answer as it's clean and simple. Wish @elclanrs answered no offense. He just resourced me into this world its AWESOME :D haha. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use dates...

```
var time = "[18:37:56]";
var date = new Date("1 january 2014 " + time.substring(1, time.length - 1));

date.getHours() % 12 == 6
date.getMinutes() == 37
date.getSeconds() == 56
```

By the way, dates do need day/month/year, but since every day has the same number of hours, you can enter any date you want. It's the hours, minutes and seconds that matter.

Comment: This is for a chat functionality that is already implemented on our forum sites. We don't have access to the php so I do these little JS 'hacks'. I don't think this would be very useful in the long run.

Comment: This is javascript... Javascript has a Date type.

Comment: HAHA I know this, I'm saying the implementation of this isn't very plausible unless it's going off my time or PHP time frame.

Comment: I... don't see what php time has to do with this. You just take the time string "[18:37:56]" as you got it in your original post, and you extract the hours, minutes and seconds from it?

Comment: Oh ok I see what your doing. Your using the string as the input of the new date then modular it for the hours. ;) I thought you were using the gethours for the hours. That's a big Simpson D'oh :D lol my bad